# Extract specific fields from tabular file with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a tabular file with such structure :

```
NAME                    ZONE
comp-envA-teamA-c9     europe-west4-a
comp-envA-teamA-11b    europe-west4-c
comp-envA-teamB-7r-v6  europe-west4-b
comp-envB-teamB-hx86   europe-west4-a
comp-envB-teamC-lbn7   europe-west4-c
envB-teamC-lcnh        europe-west4-a
```

I would like extract some part of these lines to get this expected output for first lines :

```
"comp-envA-teamA-c9" is for "teamA" in zone "europe-west4-a"
"comp-envA-teamA-11b" is for "teamA" in zone "europe-west4-c"
"comp-envA-teamB-7r-v6" is for "teamB" in zone "europe-west4-b"
```

I tried a lot of things with awk but was not able to manage it..

my ideas was to first create in an initial awk with delimiter tab an array which assign second element to the first one : ie tab[comp-envA-teamA-c9]=europe-west4-a

and next in a second awk with delimiter "-" to get the team information.

However I was not able to create such array and transmit it to a second awk

many thx for any help!

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please post expected output in your post too and let us know then.

Comment: I reworded to be more clear I hope

Comment: Not clear as of now too, please mention expected output in your post and let us know your efforts too which you have put to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If word team* can be anywhere in first string you can lock only on that word and separators [- ].

AWK solution:

```
awk 'NR>1 { match($1,/team[^- ]+/); print("\"" $1 "\" is for \"" substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH) "\" in zone \"" $2 "\""); }'
```

Test:

```
$ awk 'NR>1 { match($1,/team[^- ]+/); print("\"" $1 "\" is for \"" substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH) "\" in zone \"" $2 "\""); }' teams.txt
"gke-envA-teamA-c9" is for "teamA" in zone "europe-west4-a"
"gke-envA-teamA-11b" is for "teamA" in zone "europe-west4-c"
"gke-envA-teamB-7r-v6" is for "teamB" in zone "europe-west4-b"
"gke-envB-teamB-hx86" is for "teamB" in zone "europe-west4-a"
"gke-envB-teamC-lbn7" is for "teamC" in zone "europe-west4-c"
"envB-teamC-lcnh" is for "teamC" in zone "europe-west4-a"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    function wrap_quotes(str){
        return "\""str"\""
    } 
    NR>1{
        split($1,name_infos,"-");
        print wrap_quotes($1) " is for " wrap_quotes(name_infos[length(name_infos) - 1]) " in zone " wrap_quotes($2)
    }' filename
```

Returns

```
"comp-envA-teamA-c9" is for "teamA" in zone "europe-west4-a"
"comp-envA-teamA-11b" is for "teamA" in zone "europe-west4-c"
"comp-envA-teamB-7r-v6" is for "7r" in zone "europe-west4-b"
"comp-envB-teamB-hx86" is for "teamB" in zone "europe-west4-a"
"comp-envB-teamC-lbn7" is for "teamC" in zone "europe-west4-c"
"envB-teamC-lcnh" is for "teamC" in zone "europe-west4-a"
```

Comment: almost this, for the last line, I would expect to have teamC and not lcnh for the second part

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { ofmt = "\"%s\" is for \"%s\" in zone \"%s\"\n" }
NR>1 {
    n = split($1,t,/-/)
    printf ofmt, $1, t[(n>3?3:2)], $2
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"comp-envA-teamA-c9" is for "teamA" in zone "europe-west4-a"
"comp-envA-teamA-11b" is for "teamA" in zone "europe-west4-c"
"comp-envA-teamB-7r-v6" is for "teamB" in zone "europe-west4-b"
"comp-envB-teamB-hx86" is for "teamB" in zone "europe-west4-a"
"comp-envB-teamC-lbn7" is for "teamC" in zone "europe-west4-c"
"envB-teamC-lcnh" is for "teamC" in zone "europe-west4-a"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering Perl.. it is just one liner

```
/tmp> cat thomas.txt
comp-envA-teamA-c9     europe-west4-a
comp-envA-teamA-11b    europe-west4-c
comp-envA-teamB-7r-v6  europe-west4-b
comp-envB-teamB-hx86   europe-west4-a
comp-envB-teamC-lbn7   europe-west4-c
envB-teamC-lcnh        europe-west4-a
/tmp> perl -lane ' /(team.*?)-/; print "\"$F[0]\" is for \"$1\" in zone \"$F[1]\"" ' thomas.txt
"comp-envA-teamA-c9" is for "teamA" in zone "europe-west4-a"
"comp-envA-teamA-11b" is for "teamA" in zone "europe-west4-c"
"comp-envA-teamB-7r-v6" is for "teamB" in zone "europe-west4-b"
"comp-envB-teamB-hx86" is for "teamB" in zone "europe-west4-a"
"comp-envB-teamC-lbn7" is for "teamC" in zone "europe-west4-c"
"envB-teamC-lcnh" is for "teamC" in zone "europe-west4-a"
/tmp>
```